# Django: saving dynamic forms with foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I would like to seek assistance and guidance to my problem.

I have the following models:

```
class myinfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)


class mynumbers(models.Model):
    fkey = models.ForeignKey("myinfo")
    Job_Position = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
```

The `mynumbers` model is dynamically generated via [django-dynamic-formset](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset).

My form

```
class info(ModelForm):
    name= forms.CharField( max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        model = APPLICANT_DATA
        fields = ('name',)

class numbers(ModelForm):
    number = forms.CharField( max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        model = APPLICANT_DATA
        fields = ('number',)
```

If you want to save your dynamic form fields you have to do this in views

```
for field in formset:
    field.save()
```

My views:

```
def index(request):

    aformset = formset_factory(numbers)
    formset = aformset(request.POST)
    form = info(request.POST)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        if form.is_valid():
            if formset.is_valid():
                for field in formset:
                    formset.save()

                form.save()
```

But the problem starts when my dynamically generated field has a foreign key(`mynumbers`) which raises an error `must be a myinfo instance`. How would I save the 2 forms where `mynumbers` has a foriegn key to `myinfo`? Is there a better way to what I did? Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where `inlineformset_factory` would be used. This allows you to have a parent model and a number of child models (related w/ parent via a foreignkey) and save them together. There are many arguments that can be passed to the inlineformset_factory in order to customize behavior (such as the minimum and maximum number of inline forms allowed, whether the user can delete inline forms, etc.) but the crux is shown below.

```
# views.py

from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
from my_app.forms import numbers as NumberForm
from my_app.forms import info as InfoForm
from my_app import models

myFormset = inlineformset_factory(models.myinfo,
    models.mynumbers,
    form=NumberForm
)

def index(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = InfoForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            info = form.save(commit=False)
            formset = myFormset(request.POST, instance=info)
            if formset.is_valid():
                info.save()
                formset.save()
                return HttpResponse('saved successfully')
    else:
        form = InfoForm()
        formset = myFormset(instance=models.myinfo())
    return render_to_response("recipes/submit.html", {
                                                    "form": form,
                                                    "formset":formset,    
                                                    }, 
                            context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**Please note**: In your question, you typed `for field in formset: formset.save()`. A formset is a collection of forms, not a collection of fields.

Formsets can be tricky and require the template rendered correctly with additional template components that are not part of regular forms (such as the `management_form` variable that allows for Django to properly process what has been added/deleted/moved/changed). It's definitely worth doing some tutorials in order to get an idea of best practices so that you don't go down a troubleshooting rabbithole w/ your custom implementation. 
I suggest [this post from Charles Leifer](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/djangos-inlineformsetfactory-and-you/) as a good entry to get acquainted with the basics.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Whenever i try to save the `formset` it always raise an error saying that there is no `formset.save()`, but when i looped it it saves, anyway, I'll try your answer for a bit thanks.

Comment: Make sure you have  myFormset = inlineformset_factory(models.myinfo,
    models.mynumbers,
    form=NumberForm
) outside of your view; this is required in addition to instantiating your formset with formset = myFormset(instance=...) inside of the view.

Comment: Works great, thanks, how does `inlineformset_factory` works exactly?

Comment: `inlineformset_factory` is a constructor for creating any number of forms for a particular model (grouped as a formset) that all have a foreign key to the same parent model. Using an inlineformset_factory, you could create a form (for myinfo) and matching formset (for mynumbers) where a user could edit a single myinfo instance and as many or few mynumbers instances as you set in the rules. Formsets are tricky, but once you get the hang of it they are very powerful.

I suggest checking out some tutorials such as this - http://charlesleifer.com/blog/djangos-inlineformsetfactory-and-you/